# Get multiple PDF reports from SSRS

Tags: python, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, pdf

I'm trying to save multiple PDF files from a SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services) website that has been created by on of our suppliers.

Scenario: To create the report you first have to set a from and until date.
Then choose a customer in dropdown menu and execute view report button to create the report.
Last step is to save the report as a PDF file.

In this last step a new tab has been opened by a `Javascript:void(0)`.
The tab will be closed and the file has been downloaded.
(I think this could be a problem while looping the request)

The Report page is then still there.

I was able to create one PDF file and change the dropdown menu with different customer names.

But when I trying to loop the PDF request the ID to identify dropdown menu get lost.

Result in this error code:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"No node with given id found"}
```

Code that I'm trying to use:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()

prefs = {
   "download.prompt_for_download": False,
   "download.directory_upgrade": True,
   "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https:\\SSRSwebsite\report\report") #Site has been removed for security reasons.


#A short moment to fill in date manually. Will be improved later on.
time.sleep(10)

#Find frame where ID could be found.
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe[@class="viewer"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

#location of pulldown menu get all selections that are possible.
listofelements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl07$ddValue"]/option')

#Loop to fill in the each option and create the PDF file.
for i in range(1, len(listofelements)):
    time.sleep(10)
    #Fill in dropdown menu
    Dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID,"ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_ddValue"))
    Dropdown.select_by_value(listofelements[i].get_attribute("value"))
    
    #button to create report
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl00']").click()
    time.sleep(3)

    #Open save menu
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00").click()

    #Create PDF to download. This button creates a new tab and closed directly after is has been created.
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@title='PDF']").click()
```

Things that I have tried:

- Switch to the first tab as soon as the PDF button has been clicked.
- Tried to open the page in different tabs and executed it one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just resolved the issue by adding the listofelements again to the loop.

```
listofelements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl07$ddValue"]/option')
```

Complete loop:

```
    #Loop to fill in the each option and create the PDF file.
    for i in range(1, len(listofelements)):
    time.sleep(10)
    #Fill in dropdown menu
    Dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID,"ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl07_ddValue"))
                    Dropdown.select_by_value(listofelements[i].get_attribute("value"))
                    
                    #button to create report
                    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl00']").click()
                    time.sleep(3)
            
                #Open save menu
                driver.find_element(By.ID, "ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00").click()
            
#Create PDF to download. This button creates a new tab and closed directly after is has been created.
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@title='PDF']").click()
    
#Add this line again:
    listofelements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl07$ddValue"]/option')
```